# NSAlert Close Alert Programmatically when using beginSheetModalForWindow:

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to close a modal alert sheet programmatically when called like this:

```
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:contacts modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(myAlertEnded:code:context:) contextInfo:NULL];
```

Comment: Hi Rob, the question was formed more like a statement I guess in the subject line, but implied and already answered by Roger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have a method like this in your controller (the `modalDelegate`):

```
- (IBAction) cancelClicked: (id) sender {

    // Cancel the sheet and close.
    [NSApp endSheet: [self window]];

}
```

... which would be wired to a Cancel button in the modal sheet (or to an OK button for that matter but that would probably invoke some spin-off processing).

You also need to implement this `didEndSelector` to actually remove the sheet:

```
- (void) didEndSheet: (id) modalSheet returnCode: (NSInteger) returnCode contextInfo: (void*) contextInfo {

    // Remove the sheet.
    [modalSheet orderOut: nil];

}
```

If I remember correctly I scooped this from an example in the Apple docs.

Comment: Thanks Roger, yes that is what I was trying to sort out.

Comment: Note, `endSheet ` is deprecated in 10.10

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and I solved this way.

1. To launch the sheet:

   ```
   [myAlertSheet beginSheetModalForWindow:self.view.window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(showAlertDidEnd: returnCode: contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
   ```
2. To programmatically close the modal sheet:

   ```
   [NSApp endSheet:[myAlertSheet window]];
   ```

`myAlertSheet` is an `NSAlert` instance variable to keep track of the modal sheet on-screen. The endSheet message then calls the selector:

```
- (void)showAlertDidEnd:(NSAlert *)alert returnCode:(int)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{...}
```

I hope the above is useful

Answer (score 5):

In `NSWindow` you'll find a method called `attachedSheet`. It yields a reference to a sheet attached to this window, if any. The sheet itself is also simply a `NSWindow`. Therefore, you might want to try this:

```
NSWindow *window = [NSApp mainWindow];
[[window attachedSheet] close];
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I found it we need to both `endSheet(alert.window)` and `alert.window.close()`.

```
let hostWindow = contacts

// Dismiss the sheet. Yet its window will stay on screen.
// .endSheet(:) will yield NSApplication.ModalResponse.stop

hostWindow.endSheet(alert.window) 

// Close the alert window.

alert.window.close()
```

OR

```
let hostWindow = contacts

alert.beginSheetModal(for: hostWindow) { response in
     switch response {
     case .stop: alert.window.close()
     default: fatalError("TODO")
     }           
}

// Later... Dismiss the sheet.
// .endSheet(:) will yield NSApplication.ModalResponse.stop

hostWindow.endSheet(alert.window)
```

Using NSAlert.runModal() we need instead:

```
let response = alert.runModal()

switch response {
case .stop: break
default: fatalError("TODO")
}           

// Later... Dismiss the NSApp.modalWindow
// stopModal() will yield NSApplication.ModalResponse.stop

NSApp.stopModal()
```